# Make filename as command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that have shell commands
For eg: test

I need to run this as

```
#test
```

instead of `#./test`

Anyone please help!

Comment: Is `test` a script you need to run or a file with shell functions/etc. that you need to be able to run?

Comment: there is already a command in the standard path named `test`. Avoid a whole class of debugging problems by using a distinctly separate name. Maybe `testR` or `myTest` etc. Good luck.

Comment: yes. it contain all the shell functions, but instead of running this by ./test, I need to run as 'test'

Answer (score 2):

Commands that don't have `/` in them are tried as

- shell builtins
- functions
- aliases
- executables in each component of $PATH

PATH is an environment variable that contains a colon-separated list of paths where the shell or or some of the exec system functions search for executable files.

```
PATH=$PWD:$PATH
```

Prepends the current directory, making your test executable runnable.
(As [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) mentions, appending is normally much better for security reasons as you normally don't want user-writable paths to override write-protected paths that are already part of PATH--though you do want it in this case because `test` is already a system-level executable)

It will still be preceded by the `test` shell builtin, however.
For that reason, you should name it something other than `test`, or circumvent the builtin with `$(which test)` after you modify your PATH.

In a shell, you could also make it a function (or an alias ) that would invoke the full path. That wouldn't have many bad security implications.

**Note:**
   `$PWD` is the absolute path to your current directory. You could also use `.` (or another relative path), making the PATH "change" as you `cd` along, however that is considered a bad practice for security reasons.

Comment: Never prepend `$PWD` before `$PATH`. Somebody who might have gained your users permissions might fake some binaries which are usually only installable by root. I have changed that in your answer...

Comment: @hek2mgl Yup, appending is generally better for that reason. However, if the OP insists on naming the executable `test`, prepending is the only option because test already is "a binary usually only installable by root".

Comment: Yeah, I realized that now and rolled-back my edit. However, I don't recommend to use that. Correct is `./test`

Comment: Since `test` is a built-in in `bash`, you'll never even *get* to path lookup.

Comment: `command test` will not bypass a shell-builtin, only a shell function.

Comment: Also, alias expansion happens first; the result is tried a shell function, then a shell builtin, and finally an executable found via PATH.